# Añadir variable en la sesión con Passport.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, autenticación, passport

tengo un proyecto para registro de notas en un colegio y necesito que la información que se genere dentro del sistema se almacene en base al año escolar que el usuario del sistema requiera.

La aplicación incorpora Passport.js para la autenticación de usuario, el proceso de autenticación funciona perfectamente pero decidí añadir al formulario de login un campo adicional(`anio_lectivo`) para seleccionar el año escolar en el cual se desea trabajar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, la idea es que en base al año escolar seleccionado yo capturo su identificador para poder usarlo por ejemplo al ingresar las notas de un alumno, se registra también el ´anio_lectivo´ que el usuario del sistema seleccionó.

A continuación adjunto el código fuente de la autenticación passport.js, el login funciona correctamente pero me veo en la necesidad de capturar el identificador `anio_lectivo` y almacenarlo en la variable de sesión para de esta manera utilizarlo en operaciones internas.

Para capturarlo y añadirlo a la variable de sesión e agregado unas líneas de código que están identificadas por la etiqueta `//TODO:`.

```js
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const db = require('../../databaes');
const bcrypt = require('./helpers');

var al;
passport.use('local.signin', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, async (req, username, password, done) => {
    try {
        al = req.body.anio_lectivo; //TODO: obtengo el id del año lectivo seleccionado
        let user = await db.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND user_state = 1', [username]);
        if (user.length > 0) {
            user = user[0];
            if (await bcrypt.matchPassword(password, user.password)) {

                done(null, user, req.flash('type', 'success'), req.flash('message', `Bienvenido ${user.fullname}`));

            } else {
                done(null, null, req.flash('type', 'warning'), req.flash('message', 'La contraseña es incorrecta'))
            };
        } else {
            done(null, null, req.flash('type', 'danger'), req.flash('message', `El usuario "${username}" no existe. `));
        }

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`-> ERROR in passport.js message: ${e.message}`);
        return e;
    }

}));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.iduser);
    
})
passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    try {
        let user = await db.query('SELECT * FROM user JOIN rol on rol.idrol = user.rol_idrol where iduser = ? ', [id]);
        //TODO: obtengo el anio_lectivo que el usuario selecciono
        const anio_lectivo = await db.query('SELECT * FROM anio_lectivo WHERE idanio_lectivo = ?', [al]);
        //TODO: añado el id a la variable de sesión 
        if (anio_lectivo.length > 0) {
            user[0].idanio_lectivo = anio_lectivo[0].idanio_lectivo;
            user[0].anio_lectivo = anio_lectivo[0].anio_lectivo;
        }
        done(null, user[0]);
        
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`-> ERROR in passport.js@deserializeUser message: ${e.message}`);
        return e;
    }
});
```

Ahora bien, esto funciona a simple vista, puedo realizar las operaciones en la aplicación y almacenarlas en base al ´idanio_lectivo´ que el usuario selecciona. Pero el gran problema surge cuando otro usuario accede a su perfil y selecciona un año escolar distinto. Entonces sucede que en la variable de sesión se registra el ultimo `idanio_lectivo` que fue seleccionado en el inicio de sesión.

Dicho de otra manera:
El usuario ´Administrador´ esta trabajando normalmente en el año académico `2018-2019` y de pronto inicia sesión el usuario `Secretaria` y accede a la aplicación con el año académico `2019-2020`, ahora el sistema reflejara a ambos usuarios el último año académico con el que se inició la sesión en el sistema.

Qué puedo hacer para que cada usuario trabaje conforme al ´anio_lectivo´ que necesitan. Quizás almacenar ese identificador en la base de datos conjuntamente con la información de usuario que registra passport.js y si es así como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que tienes una variable global común para todas las sesiones, en lugar de crear una para cada usuario *online*.

Podrías hacer algo tan sencillo como usar un *mapa* para guardar el año lectivo de cada usuario, por ejemplo

```
let al= new Map();
```

Y cuando confirmas que el usuario está autenticado, guardas **su** año lectivo:

```
let user = await db.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND user_state = 1', [username]);
  if (user.length > 0) {
    user = user[0];
    if (await bcrypt.matchPassword(password, user.password)) {
      al.set(username,req.body.anio_lectivo); //guardado en el mapa
      ...
```

Y cuando quieras hacer cualquier acción posterior, recuperas el año lectivo del usuario:

```
let anioLectivo=al.get(username);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo sinceramente haría lo que has comentado, de hecho tengo una aplicacion con Passport y guardo en la base de datos el Token del usuario logueado por si se conecta desde varios dispositivos, añade un campo a la entidad usuario que sea la fecha en la que esta trabajando, y al cerrar session o bien te cargas la cookie, local storage(donde lo almacenes en el front) y del back te cargas el campo de la base de datos